# Normalize the NDVI raster 0-255

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-calculator, ndvi

NDVI values raster computed by using the band 3 and band 4 reflectance values b4-b3/b4+b3. The output raster is of 32bit type formate although the possible ranges that shows in statistics parameter are from -0.35 to +0.65. Are this is due to abnormal values that have been accounted for no data values. If yes then how can i remove those values from the output raster or make them out during the calculation of NDVI in raster calculator.

@Whuber. commented in a post [normalize raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/50169/36828), but cannot understand how to do into my case of ration images. there are 5 images that i took for comparison but how do i normalize them to compare easily

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a lot of questions, not just one.

> Are this is due to abnormal values that have been accounted for no data values.

NoData values will be excluded from calculations. If the value of 0 is being used to notate NoData, you are going to have bad results. Check the attribute table to see what your data uses (other popular choices are -999 and the like).

> the possible ranges that shows in statistics parameter are from -0.35 to +0.65.

The valid range of NDVI values are {-1, 1}. Your value ranges are within the expected range of NDVI values.

> NDVI raster 0-255

This is not a good idea, but it is possible using a bit of algebra.

Not a good idea because it is already normalized for comparison between images (that's what the N stands for in NDVI).
The range of NDVI values are {-1, 1}. Usually < 0 means not vegetation and > 0 means vegetation. It is likely that you need to calibrate your NDVI to your specific images by comparing various pixel thresholds with manually classified data (vegetation/no vegetation) to somewhere around .1-.2.

Comment: +1 Good answers.  However, it is often useful to stretch NDVI from 0 - 255, such as with NAIP imagery, in order to store data in unsigned 8-bit integer format rather than float.  This can save a lot of disk space and increase processing efficiency.

Comment: floor((x+1)*127.9999) will give you the 0-255 conversion

Answer (score 0):

> NDVI raster 0-255

You cannot represent NDVI values to some wide grey scale 0-255 because that doesn't make any sense.

NDVI only shows areas with vegetation cover and those that are not. Hence, geting some ranges to represent some kind of shrubs, built-up areas or water are not actually correct. Many though do try to do so by thresholding but believe I believe thats not scientific but ended up having fun playing around with data.