# Using ModelBuilder to get Max and Min Values from raster to raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator

I'm building a model (ModelBuilder) at ArcMap 10.3.1. How can I get an output (can be a string) of the maximum and the minimum value of a raster to use it on raster calculator?

Actually I'm using the Get Raster Properties tool, and the result I'm putting on raster calculator like this:

-> Square("%raster%" - "%raster_max%"/"%raster_max%" - "%raster_min%")

My problem is that the Get Raster Properties does not export a string with the value. I would like to know if there is a tool or a way using ModelBuilder to extract to Max and Min value of a raster to directly apply on Raster Calculator.

edit: I tried to use Calculate Value tool, with the code:

```
import arcpy
#Get the geoprocessing result object
maxValueResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("c:.../..", "MAXIMUM")
#Get the MAX value from geoprocessing result object
maxValue = maxValueResult.getOutput(0)
```

But it keeps exporting the number only in the results, and it does not convert into a string to use on raster calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the raster has already had statistics calculated,  you can access the max and min values in the raster calculator directly using `"your_raster".maximum` and `"your_raster".minimum` syntax. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192913/2856) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a silly model that gets the MAXIMUM value of a raster and then adds it to itself then takes the square:

[image: Using maximum value]

There is no need to convert the output of the properties tool into a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  Already tried that:  Square("%NDVI%" + float(%maxvalue%))  I think the problem is that the number have a negative or positive signal.  Error:  `Square(Raster(r"C:\...") + float(0,586451292037964))
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec
TypeError: float() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
Failed to execute (Pv Calculator)`