# Using ArcGIS ModelBuilder to reclassify by raster properties (mean)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, reclassify

I'd like to reclassify raster using ModelBuilder based on the raster properties.

For example assign 0 to all values less than mean+2, and assign 1 to other values

[image]

I could do it manually by calculating the proper value, but for sure some of you know a better way to do it.

Comment: Use the [reclassify tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm).

Comment: That screen is from that tool, but I don't know how to automatically calculate threshold eg raster mean +2

Comment: Look at the get raster properties tool if you want the mean.

Comment: I tried that, but still, don't know how to use parameter obtained from get raster properties tool in reclassify table

Comment: What does your test model so far look like?

Comment: Use inline variable substitution. This is also documented in the help file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, what you have to do is use Get Raster Properties. I am familiar with your problem of using the parameter obtained from this tool. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224507/using-modelbuilder-to-get-max-and-min-values-from-raster-to-raster-calculator) you can find a similar solution with Raster Calculator. However, I find it simpler to use the Create Constant Raster tool to create constant rasters with their values equal to the mean and standard deviation of your input raster and then do calculations based on that:

[image]

There are two connectors from Input raster to Create Constant Raster, these are for the output extent and the output cell size. Then, the mean+ 2xStdev is calculated with Times and Plus for the rasters. Then, you can use a Greater than Equal (or Less than Equal, whichever you need) to yield the final thresholded raster.

Note that this is designed for a binary threshold as you describe.