# Comparing normalize options of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.5, normalize

I am wondering if the tool “rescale by function” is definitely doing the same than the raster calculator with the expression `("raster"-min("raster"))/(max("raster")-min("raster"))*100`? (I guess so, but I am not sure about it, therefore I am asking). It is really important, as the raster calculator is not working very stable since the update to 10.5. 
This question is related to answers of the following post: [Normalizing raster using raster calculator in ArcGIS 10.3.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192595/normalizing-raster-using-raster-calculator-in-arcgis-10-3-1)

Moreover, I tried both methods with the same result, but sometimes the result grid is not reaching the value 100. However, this is the aim of the normalization.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Have you calculated statistics with no skip value? The default is to take a sample, thus returning the sample maximum and not necessarily the true max. I have a tool for doing this, in the Gradient Metrics toolbox, and other transformations that may make this less painful. https://github.com/jeffreyevans/GradientMetrics

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to download this tool. Thus I need to find another solution. Any  suggestions?